# Как прибаиндить View по ID ? ButterKnife

Tags: java, android, butterknife

В [документации](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) написано, что нужно сделать так:

```
@BindView(R.id.title) TextView title;
```

и в самом методе `onCreate()` указать:

```
ButterKnife.bind(this);
```

и потом пользоваться этим вью так как будто ты выполнил `findViewById()`...

Я так и сделал и в итоге получил `NullPointerException`.

Вот код:

```
public class TestDeleteIt extends AppCompatActivity {
    @BindView(R.id.test)
    private ImageView test;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_delete_it);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
    }

    public void clickTest(View view) {
        test.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.accent_color));
    }
}
```

Что сделал не так?

**ПРАВКА**

Вот сейчас так выглядит, я добавил функцию которая должна обрабатывать клик(не она тоже не работает) и убрал приватный модификатор...

```
public class TestDeleteIt extends AppCompatActivity {
@BindView(R.id.testIt)
ImageView testImageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_delete_it);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
}

@OnClick(R.id.imButtonAnim)
public void testSecondBtn(View view){
    Log.e("EEE", "WWWW");
}

public void testFirstBtn(View view) {
    testImageView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.accent_color));
}
}
```

**Правка2**

Project level

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
```

Module

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.krokosha.aleksey.testdeleteit"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner  "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
}
```

MainAct

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@BindView(R.id.textViewTest)
TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@OnClick(R.id.buttonTest)
public void testButton(View view){
    textView.setText("Hello");
}
}
```

Получаю oшибку

```
Could not find method testNew(View) in a parent or ancestor Context  for android:onClick attribute defined on view class  android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'buttonTest'
```

Comment: А как Вы подключаете его? apt подключили в gradle? Сделайте imageview не приватным

Comment: я поменял модификатор (добавил к вопросу), но все равно  не работет... И вот еще вопрос насчет обработки кликов... я сделал как написано, но тоже не реагирует...

Comment: А вы apt подключили? Если у вас метод серым горит, то скорее всего вы apt не подключили

Comment: в смысле зависимость в градл? да  , вот она `compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'` ... Да и если бы она не подлючилась, то я бы не добавлялись импорты при переопределении...

Comment: Это либа, в gradle еще есть строка apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0

Comment: Еще плагин нужно подключить apply plugin: 'android-apt'

Comment: Коллега сверху все написал

Comment: В `project-level` в `repositories `добавьте `mavenCentral()`.

Comment: А теперь для кнопки в `xml` добавьте атрибут `android:onClick="testButton"`. И в метод `onCreate(...)` добавьте `ButterKnife.bind(this);`.

Comment: И на будущее: лучше не делать эти `Правка 1`, `Правка 2` и т.д., ибо получается непонятная мешанина. Один вопрос – один ответ. Есть еще один вопрос – создайте новый вопрос.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/118781)

Comment: @post_zeew `mavenCentral()` добавлять не обязательно и  в `xml` атрибут `android:onClick="testButton"` тоже так как насколько я понял `ButterKnife` это делает сам. Проблема была в том, что я пока правил удалил `ButterKnife.bind(this);` из `onCreate()`... Ну и конечно ваш совет из UPD тоже помог... Странно конечно что это в докуметнации не описано... там просто сказано добавить 2 строчки...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все дело в модификаторе доступа.

Ваш `ImageView` при биндинге используется вне класса `TestDeleteIt`, следовательно, он не должен иметь модификатор доступа `private`.

Собственно, [вот комментарий](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/518) самого Jake Wharton:

> @BindView fields must not be private or static. i don't know,why??
>
> JakeWharton : Because the generated code needs to be able to assign the values.

**UPD**. Подключение библиотеки:

1. Project-level `build.gradle`:

   ```
   buildscript {
     repositories {
       mavenCentral()
      }
     dependencies {
       classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
     }
   }
   ```
2. Module-level `build.gradle`:

   ```
   apply plugin: 'android-apt'

   android {
     ...
   }

   dependencies {
     compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
     apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
   }
   ```

Comment: я поменял модификатор (добавил к вопросу), но все равно  не работет... И вот еще вопрос насчет обработки кликов... я сделал как написано, но тоже не реагирует...

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, Вы так же получаете `NPE`? В чем выражается эта неработоспособность?

Comment: Нет в случае с обработкой клика я просто не получаю ничего... И само название метода подсвечено серым, что говорит о том, что метод нигде не используется...

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, Скорее всего Вы не так подключили библиотеку. Смотрите **UPD**.

Comment: Да  и кстати забыл спросить, так это же не очень удобно если нельзя сделать поля `private or static`... Мне кажется это большой недостаток... Как думаете?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, А у Вас часто поля-`view` объявлены как `static`? Зачем?

Comment: Не статик, но приватные почти все которые вынесены как переменные класса...

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, Приватные они по той причине, что не используются извне. А при использовании `ButterKnife` появляется необходимость их использования извне. В принципе, ничего плохого не вижу, но особого смысла в этой библиотеке не вижу.

Comment: почему они приватные я понял, и я вас поддерживаю. Немного разобравшись я тоже подумал о том, что какой то явной пользы она не несет